# How draw two curves for a given dataframe?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like below:

```
        f-measure   perc%
class_0  0.98       0.25
class_1  0.86       0.25
class_0  0.98       0.33
class_1  0.86       0.33
class_0  0.97       1.00
class_1  0.75       1.00
```

How can I draw a curve line showing f-measure where the `x-axis` represents the `perc%` column and `y-axis` represents the f-measure. I think I need two curves one for `class_0` and another one for `class_1`. So how can I draw both curves in the same figure? You are allowed to modify the structure of the dataframe if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way would be using `.lineplot` from [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) package.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(x='perc%', y='f-measure', hue='index', data=df.reset_index())
```

This is the same as:

```
for c in df.index.unique():
    plt.plot(df.loc[c, 'perc%'], df.loc[c, 'f-measure'], label=c)
plt.xlabel('perc%')
plt.ylabel('f-measure')
plt.legend(title='index')
```

The output will be this:

[image]

Comment: both are not the same. The second one generate in the legend for labels